# WebRequest method does not work in a web application .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a simple console application - Console App (.Net Core) - that request external content:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "PostmanRuntime/7.26.5");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "*/*");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "deflate");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic YTph");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
var response = client.DownloadString("http://example.net");
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

And it works fine. But if the same code is inserted in ASP.NET Core Web Application returns http 400 error (Bad Request).

Why this difference between the application console and the web application?

Do I need to enable something in the web application to enable external requests?

Thanks (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: "We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class." check this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I tried but I have the same error - 400 Bad request.

I also tested with nodejs without problem. With c# with Framework 4.7.2 also works fine...I have no other ideas

Comment: I found a strange problem: web project use Net Core 2.1, but I move version 3.1, it works fine.

I tried also to create console application with my previous code that works with Net core 3.1, but returns Bad Request with Net Core 2.1.

Is version 2.1 that has a bug?

Comment: Ok I found where is the problem:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749042/httpclient-with-net-core-2-1-hangs>

Comment: if you are working with .NET Core, best to be on the latest version. glad you solved it on your own. welcome to the community.